# KVM networking: OSPF between Vyos VMs running across different hosts

Tags: networking, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

Unable to establish **OSPF neighbourhood** between **Vyos-1.3** VMs running across **different hosts**. On each host, one interface of Vyos VM's are connected to host physical interface using **'macvtap'**. Running '**tcpdump**' on host's physical interface shows OSPF packets being sent and received to multicast address. However, the Vyos VMs doesn't seem to form neighbourhood.

Suggestions on how to make it through and debug...

Regards,
Anderson

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer from posts on other forums.
It needs to enable **allmulticast** on **macvtap**!